# isIdleTimerDisabled not working for Video call iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I have a WebRTC iOS video call app and i need to set `isIdleTimerDisabled` to `true` when video call is started, so the device will not dim the display and not go to sleep after a while.

I saw that Viber does not dim the display nor it goes to sleep during a video call, but my app goes to sleep 20 seconds after a video call is established. I have made sure that i call

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
```

when video call is ended, and

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

when video call is established.

Is there something else I must do to prevent idle timer while in video call, something like in App capabilities?

Comment: Are you talking about the app running in the debug mode? Because Xcode makes debugging app ignore `isIdleTimerDisabled`.
Please, check the app behavior without debugging.

Comment: I mean this could possibly a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856099/how-to-re-enable-the-idle-timer-in-ios-once-it-has-been-disabled-to-allow-the-d